# Modify the Regex to check if sting contains no email address in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a regex that check if no email address is input that works

```
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_email', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?!\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$)/.test(value);
}, "Do not include an email address");
```

Now I need to modify it to check if a sting contains no email address.

I want:

**abc@example.com** (True)

**abc@example.com** some words (True)

some words **abc@example.com** (True)

some words **abc@example.com** some words (True)

some words (False)

Comment: To fail validation, you want `false`, and to pass validation you want `true`.  All of your booleans are backwards based on your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the input text does not match a string that contains an email. So, you can follow two approaches here:

1. Use [`/\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*/`](https://regex101.com/r/PEqBCs/3) regex and set `contains_no_email: false`
2. Use a regex that matches any string but a string containing an email-like string with [`/^(?![^]*?\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/PEqBCs/2) and use `contains_no_email: true`.

You may swap the logic by changing the `contains_no_email` value.

Here is a sample solution:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_email', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||  
           /^(?![\s\S]*?\w+(?:[-+.']\w+)*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)/.test(value);
    }, "Do not include an email address"
);

$('#myform').validate({
        // other options,
        rules: {
            "email": {
                required: true,
                contains_no_email: true
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, Can you please tell me regex to check for url the same way?

Comment: @DMP Usually, people use a very broad pattern like `/https?:\/\/\S+/`

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, you can try just surrounding your current email regex with word boundaries instead of `^` and `$` anchors:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_email', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /\b\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)\b/.test(value);
}, "Do not include an email address");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, there is an error in it `Invalid regular expression: /\b\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+\b/: Unterminated group`

Comment: Sorry was missing a closing `)` in there.

Comment: There is no error in it now,  but it does not work

Comment: There is no point using word boundaries here as there is always an implicit word boundary between start of pattern and between `\w` and `\w` and end of pattern. Anyway, the problem is not with just the regex here, code and regex should both be considered.